# Is it possible to pull data from scanned documents and dynamically have the data put into sql server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, scanning

I was wondering if I could scan a document from a scanner and have the information pulled from those document files and put into sql server database? It sounds kind of hard since wouldn't I need some kind of image analyzing software?

Sorry if the tags are wrong I honestly don't know where to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use basic .NET functionality to get the scanned version of the document (e.g. JPEG, PDF) from user via an upload box, then you must use an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to get the content of the document as text and save them in the database.

I don't think you can directly USE the scanner, by ASP.NET.

Comment: You will probably want to find a free OCR API that can be used with .NET and use it in your project. Implementations are different, so you should refer to that specific OCR documentation. See this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085/free-ocr-library)

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest to you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451169/Csharp-Optical-Marks-Recognition-OMR-Engine-1-0